# answers.ros.org feedback broken

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to provide feedback on the [badges web page](http://answers.ros.org/badges/) but when you click on feedback at the top of the page, it tries to send you to http://answers.ros.org/badges/%(feedback_faq_url)s which comes up "400 Bad Request".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31829/answers.ros.org-feedback-broken/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-15**:
Confirmed. Please file a ticket here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros against answers.org.org and then "answer" this question with the link to the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears to be fixed now.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1